# Removing glow, border, vertical/horizontal scrolls of a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea which I still find ugly to deal with. I have done all the decorations to it but still have some issues with it.
The glow and the border won't still go away and it is annoying. Is it the `form-control` class? I removed it and I nearly fainted.

1. Are there any risk/compatibility issues in using `div` to get user data instead of textarea?
2. How do I actually make a textarea look quiet, soft and flexible? No border, no glow, no vertical/horizontal scrolls, no nothing. Just a plain whitespace for me to tweak.

**HMTL**:

```
<div class = 'comment_wrapper'>
    <textarea class="commment_content form-control" rows = '1' placeholder=""></textarea>
    <button class="post_cs btn btn-xs" name = "update" type="submit">Comment</button>
    <button class="post_cs btn btn-xs" name = "sms" type="submit">Cancel</button>
</div>

<div class = 'comment_wrapper'>
    <div class='commment_content' contentEditable = 'true'> 

    </div>
    <button class="post_cs btn btn-xs" name = "update" type="submit">Comment</button>
    <button class="post_cs btn btn-xs" name = "sms" type="submit">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
textarea{  #have tried class commment_content
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 0; #have tried none
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

All I need to take `div` home is to set its `contentEditable` to `True`.

[image]

Comment: Can you make an example seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/b8jg0d59/

Comment: That code tells me you're using bootstrap, is that right? And if so, which version?

Comment: @caeth: Yes, I am using version 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override bootstrap styling from `.form-control`

Change your css to this:

```
textarea{  
  outline: none;
  border: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

And you will remove the outline, border and glow from you textarea.